# OpenGL ES drawArrays draw order

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to display a sphere with TRIANGLE_STRIP in OpenGL ES but the result is weird. So I wanted to see how points are connected by drawing only any initial 4 vertices using GL_LINES_STRIP. The result is different if I allocate 4 vertices buffer or more. What is the reason?

Vertices generation:

```
 for (float angleA = -90f; angleA <90; angleA += step) {


        float r1 = (float) Math.cos(angleA * deg);
        float r2 = (float) Math.cos((angleA + step) * deg);
        float h1 = (float) Math.sin(angleA * deg);
        float h2 = (float) Math.sin((angleA + step) * deg);

        // Fixed latitude, 360 degrees rotation to traverse a weft
        for (float angleB = 0f; angleB <= 360; angleB += step) {

            float cos = (float) Math.cos(angleB * deg);
            float sin = (float) Math.sin(angleB * deg);
            float dx, dy, dz, u, w;

            float[] pt1 = new float[3];
            float[] pt2 = new float[3];

            pt1[0] = Math.round((r2 * cos) * radius);// radius*r1*sin;
            pt1[1] = Math.round((h2) * radius);//radius*h1*sin;
            pt1[2] = Math.round((r2 * sin) * radius);//*10f;radius*cos;

            pt2[0] = Math.round((r1 * cos) * radius);//radius*r2*sin;
            pt2[1] = Math.round((h1) * radius);// radius*h2*sin;
            pt2[2] = Math.round((r1 * sin) * radius);//10f;radius*cos;


            vertexBuffer.put(pt1);
            Log.d("VERTEX", "a1=" + (angleA + step) + "a2=" + (angleB) + "[" + pt1[0] + "_" + pt1[1] + "_" + pt1[2] + "]");
            vertexBuffer.put(pt2);
            Log.d("VERTEX", "a1=" + (angleA) + "a2=" + angleB + "[" + pt2[0] + "_" + pt2[1] + "_" + pt2[2] + "]");
        }
    }
```

The first 4 created vertex are [1,0,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,1] and [0,-1,0].
So I expect to see only 2 lines with GL_LINES_STRIP (the last one is just the opposite of the second one).
If I allocate buffer of size 4 and break the loop on a vertex count=4 the rendering is as expected:

```
 int nbPts = 4;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(nbPts * 3 * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
```

Drawing part:

```
 mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "position");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, COORDS_PER_VERTEX * floorPoints, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Now if I add all the points `int nbPts = (int)((180/step)*(360/step+1))*2;` and let the loop add all the points to the buffer the displayed result of

```
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

is 2 lines (like as the last point is not [0,-1,0])

Comment: What's the value of `floorPoints`?

Comment: it's the number of added points, initialized to 0 and incemented of 2 at the end of inner loop:
`floorPoints+=2;`
if i replace by 4 instead it's fixed, thanks! (but this behavior seems strange to me)

Comment: Any idea why the result figure is not a correct polyhedron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments used for this `glVertexAttribPointer()` call look questionable:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, COORDS_PER_VERTEX * floorPoints, vertexBuffer);
```

The 5th argument is the stride, which is the difference in bytes between two values of the attribute. With only the vertex positions stored in the buffer, this corresponds to the size of one vertex position, which is `COORDS_PER_VERTEX` `GLfloat` values. So the call should be:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, COORDS_PER_VERTEX * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer);
```

As long as the attribute is tightly packed, you can also pass `0` for the stride:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertexBuffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for unlocking me! 
I misunderstood the 5th parameter usage.